# Comparing Password After Converting into Decimal

Tags: php, hash, password-hash, sha512

Recently I was working on a PHP application and comparing DB stored password (which was generated and stored in C# application using sha512) in my PHP application.

As I can see, I could not compare password using base64 or even with hex values. But then I converted them into decimal and I was able to compare and both passwords (input and stored).

Here is an example code I was using (both contains sha512 binary hash):

```
$storedpass = $DBModel->password;
if (hexdec($passwordHash) === hexdec($storedpass)) {
 return true;
}
```

The code returned true in this way;

My question is, their base64 values are not same, their hex are not same, but their decimal values are same. Is this the right way to compare passwords ? Am I having any vulnerability here ?

Comment: Did you look at the password_verify? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: Why do you need to apply a function to both strings before comparing them? As about hexdec(), with proper data loss any pair of strings can be made equal ([example](https://3v4l.org/Yh3fP)) but it'd be easier to figure out if you shared your sample data.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzálezI was just playing with different things and ended up hexdec result. Now i understood that should not be the way to deal with passwords.

Comment: `password_verify()`, if that's what you mean, only works with passwords generated by `password_hash()`. I'm talking about plain variable comparison: why would you need e.g. `if (base64_encode($colour) === base64_encode('pink') )` instead of just `if ($colour === 'pink')`?

Comment: if `$passwordHash` and `$storedpass` are not the same (use case-insensitive comparison), but the hex-to-decimal conversions are the same, then I think you have a really big problem. If you want help, you have to show us more code, and also give us an example with real values.

Answer (score 0):

A properly salted password hash can never be compared, because the random salt will produce different hashes for each calculation. Only unsafely stored passwords can be compared and this is a security risk you should not take.

That's why password hash functions exist, in PHP you would do it like this:

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($_POST['password'], $existingHashFromDb);
```